# Acess denied to admin@% to Aurora RDS Mysql8 mysql database

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I recently migrated my RDS Aurora Mysql cluster from 5.7 to 8.x version.

After the migration I see I don't have anymore the permission to create a stored procedure in the mysql database.

This is the stored procedure I want to create and I need to run it on mysql because I need the list of all databases:

```
    DELIMITER $$

USE `mysql`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_flyway_item`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_flyway_item`(`version` VARCHAR(50),`checksum` INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE db_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys','metabase','tmp');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO db_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @query = CONCAT('UPDATE `', db_name, '`.`flyway_schema_history` SET checksum=',`checksum`,' WHERE version=', `version`';');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but I get this response:

```
3 queries executed, 2 success, 1 errors, 1 warnings

Query: USE `mysql`

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.015 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.015 sec
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `update_flyway_item`

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Execution Time : 0.015 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.016 sec

Note Code : 1305
PROCEDURE mysql.update_flyway_item does not exist
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_flyway_item`(`version` VARCHAR(50),`checksum` INT(11)) BEGIN DECLARE done INT DEFAU...

Error Code: 1044
Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.015 sec
```

Is there a way to allow admin user to create a stored procedure in mysql database? I feel like this setting has been restricted after last update.